# C++ printing a struct in hexadecimal while preserving the order of the field

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to print the hexadecimal values of a struct iteratively but when I print them the order of the print gets rearranged due to how the struct is looped.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test {
    uint16_t t;
};

int main() {
    Test t = Test();
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *) &t;
    t.t = 16468;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(t); i++) {
        printf("%02X", ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example code, the output to the console is 5440, but the actual value of the item in the struct should be outputted as 4054. This is because 2 bytes are processed at a time. How do I loop over the struct and print out the value of the items in the struct while preserving its order?

Comment: The order depends on the endianess of your machine - so what you see is how the struct is actually layed out in memory.

Comment: Yes. I would like to print the field with regards to the endianness of my machine.

Comment: `Test t = Test();` --> `Test t;`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like it to be printed in big-endian byte order even if your machine is a little endian machine? In that case, you need to read the value of each field in the struct individually and then convert the value to big-endian if needed.

Comment: @Anonymous -- The comment section is for comments, not answers.

Comment: I suppose that is possible but I am working without direct access to the fields, only the byte values

Comment: Ok, and what is your actual goal here? Why isn't the native byte order good? If you don't have access to the fields, you will not know what bytes to reverse in order to make them big-endian.

Comment: Have you tried using `uint16_t` pointer instead of 2 8-bit values?

Comment: The actual goal here is that I am working to integrate two pieces of software, one is endien aware and the other is not. If I am able to make one edien aware I can integrate the two together

Comment: @Anonymous Ok, then you must read and convert each field separately or automate it using some library, like protobufs etc.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/boostorg/pfr for a way to automate it.

Comment: A tip on writing test cases: if you're concerned about how a value is displayed in hex, set it with a hex value. That way you don't have so tell yourself that 16468 should show up as 4054. Set it to 0x4054 and see if that's what you get on output.

Comment: I always like to think in terms of `network byte order`. Its well defined. https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl